# Free memory from stack in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, stack

Just wondering if there is a way to free or reduce the memory allocated from the stack at runtime.
Ex:

```
int num[10] = {1,2,3,4};
```

Can I free the 6*4 bytes (Assuming int requires 4 bytes) at runtime?

Comment: See [C11 Standard - 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4)

Answer (score 1):

The memory used by local variables is reclaimed when the block they are defined in ends.  They can't be free'ed the way dynamically allocated memory can.

If you need to adjust the amount of memory you're using, allocate memory with `malloc` / `free`:

```
int *num = malloc(NUM_BYTES);
...
int *tmp = realloc(num, NEW_NUM_BYTES);
if (tmp) num = tmp;
...
free(num);
```

Comment: Yes I understand that. My question is - Can I reduce the amount of memory I got from stack at runtime. In this case 24 bytes of memory.

Comment: @SaurabhSuman No you can't.  If you want to change the amount of memory in use you should use `malloc` / `free` instead.

Comment: @SaurabhSuman: You asked for 10 integers, four with non-zero values and six with zeros to start with.  The compiler can't do the job you asked it to do with less.  If you'd written `int num[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, };` then you'd save the space.  Since initializers are fixed at compile time, the choice is up to you — C makes you think.

Comment: The lifetime of objects with automatic storage duration ends when execution of their block ends, not when they go out of scope. Lifetime is a duration in time. Scope is location in code. When a function calls another, its identifiers are not in the scope of the called function’s code, but its objects continue to exist. (Also, during a function call, the calling function’s execution is suspended, not ended.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good distinction there.  Updated to reflect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The above case is just an example. In the actual case, I can have int num[MAX_SIZE] , only at runtime I populate it and now I figured out that I don't need that much space. So how can I reduce that memory?

Comment: Except VLAs.  The lifetime of a VLA really does correspond exactly to the time the program is executing the code in which that VLA is in scope.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: If `functionA()` has a VLA `int a[n];` and then calls another function, `functionB()`, the VLA `a` is out of scope but still exists while `functionB()` is executing.

Comment: You show initializers, @SaurabhSuman: those are fixed at compile time.  If the content (and hence size of the array) is determined at run time, you need to use either a VLA or dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: My apologies, @JonathanLeffler, this is a tricky word-smithing exercise.  The standard puts it exactly this way: "its lifetime extends from the declaration of the object until execution of the program leaves the scope of the declaration."  This is pretty much what dbush initially described, and different from other automatic variables, whose lifetimes start when execution enters their *block* (not scope) and ends when execution leaves that block.  I acknowledge that the identifier of a VLA may not be in-scope for that object's entire lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I free the 6*4 bytes (Assuming int requires 4 bytes) at runtime?

No.  Objects of automatic (or static) storage duration have fixed size for their lifetime, as determined by their declarations.  If you want to use less space, then declare a smaller object.

If you are specifically declaring a small-ish array, you do not know until runtime just what size it needs to be, and you want to declare only as much as you actually need, then you may have the alternative of using a variable-length array.  VLA support is optional in C2011, and VLAs carry some potential issues that fixed-length arrays do not, but if that's acceptable to you then you might do it like so:

```
void count_to(unsigned char max) {
    int numbers[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        numbers[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that VLAs may not have initializers, and that you can get yourself in trouble (e.g. overflow the stack) if you end up with VLAs larger than you accounted for.

Your main alternative is dynamic allocation.  Allocating your arrays dynamically has code and often performance overhead, and it requires you to be sure to free the allocated memory, but all conforming implementations support it, and it typically supports much larger objects than VLAs do.